# Using Android Device for debugging web application

Tags: android, debugging, galaxy-tab

I installed Android emulator and it is very very slow that i am not able to test my web application in it. Is there any way to debug the application directly if I have a galaxy tab device with me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hook it up using USB you can debug using a real device. Set the debugging flag to 'on'. See the manual: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html